# How to submit multiple rows tabular form data in database using code igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

Hello i am creating a school management system and facing a little problem. 
The problem is that i am having a complex form containing following fields in a table

[image]

I have a table fee structure in which i want to insert data.

having columns

```
id | classID | sectionID | feetypeID | must   | amount | active
 1       1         1           1       must      500       yes  
 2       1         1           2       optional  500       no
```

so how to create an array such that it uses above form to insert data in table.
Basically i want users to choose feetype they want to have for classes and set their amount and then choose classes they want to apply it for so an entry is created in database for each section and each feetype they select.

I don't know how to make controller and model for this but i have this code of view

**View**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
<div class="box-body">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12">

<h3>Fee Types</h3><br>
<div id="hide-table">

<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>

        <tr>
<th class="col-sm-2"><?=$this->lang->line('slno')?></th>
<th class="col-sm-2"><?=$this->lang->line('feetype')?></th>
<th class="col-sm-2"><?=$this->lang->line('amount')?></th>   
<th class="col-sm-2"><?=$this->lang->line('must')?></th>
<th class="col-sm-2"><?=$this->lang->line('active')?></th>
<th class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox"> Select All</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if(count($feetypes)) {$i = 1; foreach($feetypes as $feetype) { ?>
<tr>
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('slno')?>">
<?php echo $i; ?>
</td>
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('feetype_name')?>" name="feetypeID" value="<?php echo $feetype->feetypeID;?>">
<?php echo $feetype->feetype; ?>
</td>

<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('amount')?>" name="amount">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $feetype->defaultamount; ?>">
</td>
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('must')?>">
                                <select class="form-control" name="must">
                                <option value="MUST">Must</option>
                                <option value="OPTIONAL">Optional</option>
                                </select>

</td>
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('active')?>">
                                <select class="form-control" name="active">
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="0">No</option>
                                </select>

</td> 
                                <td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('select')?>">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="selected">
</td>

</tr>
<?php $i++; }} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h3> Apply To</h3><br>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
  <th class="col-sm-3">Class</th>
  <th class="col-sm-4">Section</th>
</thead>
<tbody> 
<?php 
foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
?>
<tr>
<td>   <input type="checkbox"><span style="font-size:18px;margin-left:10px;"> <?php echo $category->classes; ?></span>
</td>

<td>
<?php
if(!empty($category->subs)) { 

    foreach ($category->subs as $sub)  {
        echo  "<input type='checkbox'> ".$sub->section.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ;
    }

}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
    </table>
    <br><br>
                          <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<?=$this->lang->line("add_feestructure")?>" >
    </div>
</div>
</div>




            </form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function addfeestructure(){
    $usertype = $this->session->userdata("usertype");
    if($usertype == "Admin" || $usertype == "Accountant"){
        $this->data['categories'] = $this->feestructure_m->get_categories();

        $this->data['feetypes'] = $this->feestructure_m->get_feetypes();
        if($_POST){

        }
        $this->data['subview'] = "feestructure/addfeestructure";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code? what have you tried and how did it go wrong?

Comment: @SJ Sethi Show us your code. And what are the errors you facing?

Comment: I have added some code please correct it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To submit multiple fields of the same name you need to add square brackets to your the name attribute like this; `<input type="text" name="fieldName[]">`.

Then in your controller you'll use a `foreach` loop to process the form:

```
public function submitForm() {
    $fieldA = $this->input->post('fieldName'); // this will be an array

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fieldA); $i++) {
        $array = array('fieldA' => $fieldA[$i]);

        $this->your_model->addRecordToDatabase($tableName, $array);
    }
}
```